# Why an iframe after print event listener is fired after I print in the main window?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events

```
export const printPdf = (data: any) => {
  const newBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  const fileLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob)
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.src = fileLink
  iframe.id = 'print_pdf'
  iframe.name = 'print_pdf'
  // iframe.style.display = 'none'
  iframe.onload = () => {
    iframe.contentWindow!.addEventListener('afterprint', () => {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe)
    })
  }
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
  window.frames['print_pdf'].focus()
  window.frames['print_pdf'].print()
}
```

So after an iframe does printing nothing happened. But when you print the main page after a dialog closes. Listener `iframe.contentWindow!.addEventListener('afterprint', ()` started execution. Why an iframe is not listening on itself print event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not waiting for your frame content has loaded before calling the `print()` method, but do wait before attaching the event listener.
So the print dialog appears before you did attach the event listener, this blocks the js, then the print event fires, then you attach the event.

If you do call the `print()` after the page has loaded, you'll get a normal behavior and your listener will fire: https://jsfiddle.net/5qbc1pzj/

```
iframe.onload = () => {
  iframe.contentWindow!.addEventListener('afterprint', (evt) => {
    document.body.removeChild(iframe)
  });
  window.frames['print_pdf'].focus()
  window.frames['print_pdf'].print()
};
```

---

And as for why the event fires on the frame's window when you call `print()` on the main window, that's normal, since the iframe is part of the document that gets printed, it will also receive this event.

From [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#printing:event-afterprint):

> The user agent must fire an event named `afterprint` at the [relevant global object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-relevant-global) of the `Document` that is being printed, as well as any [nested browsing contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context) in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But still, I don't know why it's not working

Comment: What do you mean? It's not working because you are calling print() too soon.

Comment: yep. So I think the problem on my side) Thanks again

Comment: This is not working. I added console.log in the afterprint listener and it never reached there.

Comment: @AmritaYadav Interesting, I can't tell I really remember if I did test in Chrome when I posted that answer two years ago, but I guess I did (I normally do with all my answers). However I can confirm that the fiddle currently fails in that browser (it still works in Firefox). I will have to investigate this, but I unfortunately lack time right now, so please be patient, I'll come back to this with an update. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AmritaYadav so it seems that they now require that the call to `print()` is made from an user gesture (e.g a click event), for it to fire that event. I still didn't had time to check if it's per specs, but I already edited the fiddle's link nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. We have stopped using this feature. But I do appreciate your taking the time to track this.