# How to detect Cancel event using iframe in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, printing

Below code in html

`<iframe id="iframePdf" type="application/pdf"></iframe>`

Below code in component

```
const element: HTMLIFrameElement = document.getElementById('iframePdf') as HTMLIFrameElement;
element.focus();
const iframe = element.contentWindow;
iframe.print();
```

Now I want to detect cancel button of print window?
How Can I detect it?

I have gone through below link but for me, this is not working for me. I am not able to get 'printed - 1' console of this events

[Why an iframe after print event listener is fired after I print in the main window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756283/why-an-iframe-after-print-event-listener-is-fired-after-i-print-in-the-main-wind)

As per above fiddler code I have modified some code but that does not work for me.
Here is the below code which I have modified as per above fiddler

```
printOnChrome() {
  console.log('hi Print option clicked - printOnChrome');

  const iframe : HTMLIFrameElement = document.getElementById('iframePdf') as HTMLIFrameElement;
  
  // iframe.style.display = 'none'
  iframe.onload = () => {
    console.log('ONLOAD is CALLING');
    iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('afterprint', (evt) => {
      console.log("printed - 1");
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    });
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
    
  }
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```